# How do I make my logical arguments work? The code is fine but it's still not working

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(suncalc)
```

Here is a list of the first 6 rows of my data. I pulled only necessary columns for what I'm trying to do.

```
structure(list(Date.of.Capture = structure(c(18383, 18393, 18395, 
18395, 18402, 18815), class = "Date"), Month = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L), Day = c(1L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 20L, 7L), Year = c(2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L), Time.of.Capture = c("6:24", 
"6:27", "8:55", "8:55", "20:22", "6:26"), Time = structure(c(1588314240, 
1589178420, 1589360100, 1589360100, 1590006120, 1625639160), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ToD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Daytime", 
NA), lat = c(40.75336, 40.75336, 40.75336, 40.75336, 40.75336, 
40.75336), lon = c(-111.624088, -111.624088, -111.624088, -111.624088, 
-111.624088, -111.624088), sunriseEnd = structure(c(1588336111, 
1589199430, 1589372111, 1589372111, 1589976545, 1625659614), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "MST"), sunsetStart = structure(c(1588386056, 
1589250673, 1589423593, 1589423593, 1590028795, 1625713092), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "MST"), dawn = structure(c(1588334143, 1589197398, 
1589370065, 1589370065, 1589974454, 1625657442), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "MST"), dusk = structure(c(1588388024, 1589252706, 
1589425639, 1589425639, 1590030886, 1625715264), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "MST")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```

Here is the code I attempted to run to pull information from my "Time" column and compare it to my "dusk", "dawn", "sunsetStart", and "sunriseEnd" columns for all entries to then place them into categorical variables based on which "Time" the entry occured in. For example, my code attempts to take every value in "Time" column greater than "dawn" column & every value less than "sunriseEnd" column to place it in the "ToD" column as "Dawn" (and continue with all other arguments if untrue).

```
md$ToD<-NA

for(i in 1: nrow(md)){
  if (md$Time[i] > md$dawn[i] & md$Time[i] < md$sunriseEnd[i]){
    md$ToD[i] <- "Dawn"
  } else if (md$Time[i] > md$sunsetStart[i] & md$Time[i] < md$dusk[i]){
    md$ToD[i] <- "Dusk"
  } else if (md$Time[i] > md$dusk[i] & md$Time[i] < md$dawn[i]){
    md$ToD[i] <- "Nighttime"
  } else if (md$Time[i] > md$sunriseEnd[i] & md$Time[i] < md$sunsetStart[i]){
    md$ToD[i] <- "Daytime"
  }
}

unique(md$ToD)
```

Below is code I used to format my columns in a way that suncalc could use them and then created a separate dataframe in which I left joined to the main "md" dataframe.

```
md$Time <- paste0(md$Year, "-", md$Month, "-", md$Day,  " ", md$Time.of.Capture,":00")

md$Time <- ymd_hms(md$Time)

md$Date.of.Capture <- paste0(md$Year, "-", md$Month, "-", md$Day)

md$Date.of.Capture <- as.Date(md$Date.of.Capture, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "MST")

timesofday <- getSunlightTimes(date = md$Date.of.Capture, 
                               lat = 40.753360, lon = -111.624088, 
                               tz="MST", keep=c("sunriseEnd", "sunsetStart", "dawn", "dusk"))

md <- left_join(md, timesofday, by = c("Date.of.Capture" = "date"))
```

I was expecting these logical arguments to work but for some reason they don't. It may be something in the way the formatting code was written because the problem seems to be within the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

{dplyr} and `findInterval` offer a succinct approach to categorize the time of day, given your example dataframe *md*:

```
library(dplyr)

ToD_names <- c('dawn', 'daytime', 'dusk', 'nighttime')

md |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(ToD = findInterval(Time, c(-Inf, dawn, sunriseEnd, sunsetStart, dusk)),
         ToD = ToD_names[1 + ToD]                     
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `case_when` and `between` to define the categories.

Your input data has `Time` in one timezone and the sunrise/sunset times in another. I assume this is an error and the time zone should be redefined.

```
md$Time[1]
[1] "2020-05-01 06:24:00 UTC"

md$dawn[1]
[1] "2020-05-01 04:55:43 MST"
```

You can use

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

md %>%
  mutate(Time = ymd_hm(paste(Date.of.Capture, Time.of.Capture), tz = 'MST'),
         ToD = case_when(
           between(Time, dawn, sunriseEnd) ~ 'Dawn',
           between(Time, sunsetStart, dusk) ~ 'Dusk',
           between(Time, sunriseEnd, sunsetStart) ~ 'Daytime',
           TRUE ~ 'Nighttime',
         ))
```